# write command does not work

Tags: write

I have 2 users : User1 is connected on tty1 and User2 is connected on tty2.

The output of `mesg` on both ttys is `is y`.

On tty1, when I type `write User2 tty2`, I get `write: User2 has messages disabled on tty2`.

What am I forgetting?

EDIT: My operating system is Arch Linux and no ssh is involved.

Comment: Can you add users to group tty, and check again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here on my debian 8 system, /usr/bin/write is symlink to /usr/bin/bsd-write and have setgid tty group and /dev/tty{0..63} are group writable.

Comment: Adding the users to tty group solved it.